# Find p for $\int_{1}^{2}(\frac{x}{(x-1)^p})\,dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration

Find p for $\int_{1}^{2}(\frac{x}{(x-1)^p})\,dx$ converges

I tryed this:

\begin{align} f(x)& =\int_1^{2} \left(\frac{x}{(x-1)^p}\right)\,\mathrm dx < \lim_{t \to 1^+}\int_t^{2}\frac{2}{(x-1)^p}\,\mathrm dx = \Big[\frac{2(x-1)^{-p+1}}{1-p}\Big]_{1}^{2} =\frac{2}{1-p} - \lim_{t \to 1^+}\frac{2}{(1-p)(t-1)^{p-1}} \end{align}

From here I can see that f(x) converges for p<1

The answers said that f(x) converges for p<2, and I don't know why.

Comment: You have shown that the integral converges if $p\lt 1$. You have not shown that it diverges if $p\ge 1$. In fact it does, if there is no typo in the question the book answer is wrong. By the way, what you call $f(x)$ is a constant.  To prove divergence, you need an inequality in a direction opposite to the one you used. The one you used was good for proving convergence if $p\lt 1$.

Comment: Is this good enough for proving divergence? $\int_1^{2} \left(\frac{x}{(x-1)^p}\right)\,\mathrm dx >  \lim_{t \to 1^-}\frac{1}{(1-p)(t-1)^{p-1}} $

Comment: Also, if I compared x using the comparison test with limit. With the constant g(x)=1. Then by the comparison test they would converge and diverge together so that would be the same as what I did. Am I right?

Comment: It is best not to try to do two things at once, but the ratio of the functions stays between $1$ and $2$, so it could be done that way.  And as to your earlier comment, yes that is the inequality.

Answer (score 0):

We have:
$$ I(p) = \int_{1}^{2}\frac{x\,dx}{(x-1)^p} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{-p}(x+1)\,dx $$
so if $p\geq 1$, $f(x)=x^{-p}(x+1)$ has a non-integrable singularity in a right neighbourhood of zero.
On the other hand, you showed that the integral is converging for $p<1$, so there is little to prove.
We have:
$$ I(p) = \frac{3-2p}{(p-1)(p-2)} $$
for any $p$ such that $\text{Re}(p)<1$. The book is simply wrong.

Comment: Alright, thank you, btw the first line you wrote - when you moved from $\int_{1}^{2}$ to $\int_{0}^{1}$ can be done on any polynomial integral?

Comment: @Lee: it is true in general in virtue of the translation-invariant property of the Lebesgue measure. $f(x)$ is integrable over $(a,b)$ iff $f(x+\tau)$ is integrable over $(a-\tau,b-\tau)$, and in such a case the two integrals are the same.